# how to get $2/(t^2 + 1)$ as the derivative for Sin(theta) when $\tan(\theta/2) = t$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, derivatives

If $\sin \theta =     \frac{2t}{1 + t^2}$

How do you get $d\theta  =  \frac{2}{1 + t^2}$

If you differentiate by quotient rule you get $\frac{2(1 - t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}$

It is part of the solution to (Australia, NSW, Board of Studies) Extension 2 HSC paper 2006, question 1 (e). The only way I can see to do it is to memorize this derivative which seems dumb, because there must be an obvious way to derive it that I can't figure??

Original question is: Use the substitution $t = \tan \frac{\theta}{2}$  to show that  ∫_(π/2)^(2π/3)▒〖dƟ/(Sin Ɵ)  =1/2  Log 3〗

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\displaystyle t=\tan\frac\theta2,$    $\displaystyle \sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$

$\displaystyle\implies \theta=2\arctan t\implies d\theta=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$

Or $\displaystyle t=\tan\frac\theta2\implies dt=\frac{\sec^2\dfrac{\theta}2}2\ d\theta=\frac{(1+t^2)\ d\theta}2$

Answer (score 0):

Using the Chain Rule directly,

$$ \Theta \ = \ \arcsin \left( \frac{2t}{1+t^2} \right) $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d \Theta}{dt} \ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \ \cdot \ 2 \ \left( \frac{1 - t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2} \right)  $$

[the part you found is only the $ \ \frac{du}{dt} \ $ "Chain Rule" factor]

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \left( \frac{2t}{1+t^2} \right)^2}} \ \cdot \ 2 \ \left( \frac{1 - t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2} \right) \  = \  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{(1 + t^2)^2 \ - \ 4t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2}}} \ \cdot \ 2 \ \left( \frac{1 - t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2} \right) $$

$$   = \  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{(1 - t^2)^2 }{(1 + t^2)^2}}} \ \cdot \ 2 \ \left( \frac{1 - t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2} \right) \  = \  \left( \frac{1 + t^2}{1 - t^2 } \right) \ \cdot \ 2 \ \left( \frac{1 - t^2}{(1 + t^2)^2} \right) \  = \    \frac{2}{1 + t^2} \ \ . $$